# Is it possible to use IE or IE functionality on a MacBook Pro?

Tags: macos, mac, firefox, internet-explorer

I am using a MacBook Pro. For some specific web sites I have to use Internet Explorer to access them (download an ActiveX control from the web site in order to access it). The web sites don't support browsers other than IE very well.

Are there any solutions to use IE or some of the IE functionality (plug-ins?) on a MacBook Pro?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solution I was thinking of was running a skeleton install in a virtual machine. Turns out someone has already [posted about doing just that](http://blog.ryanparman.com/2009/06/30/run-ie6-ie7-ie8-images-virtualbox-macosx/). He's [created VMware VMs](http://blog.ryanparman.com/2009/01/07/run-ie6-ie7-ie8-images-vmware-fusion-macosx/) that he shows how to import into VirtualBox. Free solution.

Comment: No IE Tab for Firefox on Mac?

Comment: @George2: IE Tab actually runs IE, so it wouldn't work on OS X. There's no ActiveX on OS X anyway, and IE is no longer supported on the platform.